# Can't import LocalAuthentication on Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I can't import LocalAuthentication on Xcode 6 beta.
After Adding LocalAuthentication.framework on "Link binary with libraries" i tried to import the framework/class by @import LocalAuthentication; or by #import  but Xcode don't recognise the framework.
I tried to change "Deployment target" on settings to iOS 8.0 but it didn't helped.
Any ideas?

Comment: I've faced the same problem last night. Today I realized that it looks like an issue about iOS Simulator. It worked fine when I use an iPhone 5S. Even with "Deployment Target = 5.0" and no frameworks imported. Check out screenshots. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v5o5kspl8akehm/TestProject.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2oa5aimana8sey/NoFramework.png

Comment: Yes you are right, When compiling on device it worked just fine. it is a major problem though. that means that if you import LocalAuthentication you can't run your project on simulator no more. There must be a solution for that.

Comment: can you share your code? @mapetek

Comment: @CanAksoy you can use [apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520-CH1). Just add LocalAuthentication.framework to your project. In the class you want to implement the biometric authentication add `@import LocalAuthentication;` in the import section then use apple's sample code.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No such module 'LocalAuthentication'" when trying to import in Xcode 6 using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149563/no-such-module-localauthentication-when-trying-to-import-in-xcode-6-using-sw)

Comment: @MattGibson This was asked a week before the question you reference, so it's rather the other way round. ;)

Comment: @Pascal True, but you can't mark that one as a duplicate of this one, because this one's not been answered. Given that they ask basically the same question, I figured it was the easiest way to link the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,Same Problem Occurs when i tried in Xcode 6. But It worked fine when I use an iPhone Device, change "Deployment target" on settings to iOS 7.0, build and run in Iphone device.

But Touch ID not Supported in my ipod Device and Simulator.. Its works only in iPhone 5s Device.

Answer (score 2):

FYI:

> Fixed in beta 3
>   Projects using LocalAuthentication won’t build if the Destination is set to iOS Simulator.