# "No such module 'LocalAuthentication'" when trying to import in Xcode 6 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I wanted to build a simple demo app using the new LocalAuthentication framework and Swift. I made a new Single View project, and added one line to the top of the ViewController.swift file:

```
import LocalAuthentication
```

Whereupon Xcode tells me there is no such module. Obviously very new to Swift, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021025/cant-import-localauthentication-on-xcode-6-beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem occurs with Objective-C code.
Seems like it is an issue of beta 1. If you run your project on an iOS 8 device (tested on a 5s iPhone), it will work. But it doesn't with the Simulator (Framework can't be found).

Comment: Is it still an issue with beta 2?

Comment: Haven't tried, but I read in release notes it is still an issue, yes.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in beta 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Same Problem Occurs in Xcode 6.
But It worked fine when I use an iPhone Device,
change "Deployment target" on settings to iOS 7.0, build and run in Iphone device.

But Touch ID not Supported in my ipod Device and Simulator..
Its works only in iPhone 5s Device.

Comment: same problem with XCode7beta3