# Local Authentication framework not found in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to experiment with Touch ID but Xcode 6 does not see the LocalAuthentication framework, either from a Swift file or Objective C classes.  I can import just about every other new framework such as HealthKit or HomeKit, but LocalAuthentication doesn't want to import.  I even can add it to the Link with Binaries list under Build Phases, and yet even still, wont show.  Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No such module 'LocalAuthentication'" when trying to import in Xcode 6 using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149563/no-such-module-localauthentication-when-trying-to-import-in-xcode-6-using-sw)

Answer (score 4):

Use real devices(iPhone 5C or iPhone 5S) to debug and run your app using Xcode 6 Beta. If you will try to compile your code without targeting real device it will give error, because Simulator does not provide touch scanning facility.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar issue, and the solution works:  [Can't import LocalAuthentication on Xcode 6 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021025/cant-import-localauthentication-on-xcode-6-beta)

Can't use it in Simulator, must use on device.  I'm assuming Apple will fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the Deployment Target is 8.0 in the project settings.